# How to have more than 100 results?

Tags: search, lucene

My question is simple but I can't find the answer. Is there a way to set in Lucene to retrieve an amount of results higher than 100 in a query?
Im using lucene 2.4.0 now.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Functionality for controlling the search result size and itarations over larger search results has been vastly improved in later versions of Lucene. If you have the possibility, consider upgrading to 2.9 or even 3.0.

That being said, I cannot from your post determine how exactly you get your search results returned. Perhaps you use a [Hits](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Hits.html) object? In that case you should consider using the [TopDocCollector](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocCollector.html) instead. The [TopDocCollector(int)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocCollector.html#TopDocCollector(int)) constructor allows you to specify the maximum number of hits you would like to have returned from your search.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.4.0, you can use [Searcher.search(Query query, int n)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html) method to retrieve desired number of results. The method returns `TopDocs` object.